# How to change the "Not applicable" character in SSAS Cube?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

Is it possible to change the "Not applicable" character in a SSAS olap cube from "N/A" to blank string ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the “N/A” string isn’t coming from your data source? If it’s not, check the UnknownMemberName property on the dimension.

Comment: Thank you for you reply @GregGalloway !
The thing is when you apply Cell data security on a measure, it will be displayed as "N/A" if you dont have permission. The issue with that is that it will screw the suppression of empty rows and columns.

Comment: can you share the cell security expression you are using?

Comment: Yes I'll edit the post.

Comment: @GregGalloway So as you can see the user is restricted to not be able to view Internet sales therefore the "--" character. The issue with that is that is messes with the suppression of rows option. Since the rows only suppress if they are blank, 0 or null.

Comment: can’t you just use dimension data security to restrict that measure? Then users won’t even be aware of its existence.

Comment: Thats was my original thought aswell but when I did that Cognos Analytics was throwing me errors when ever someone was not allowed to view the measure.